# LINQ to SQL, aggregation of sub-query result

Tags: linq-to-sql

Assume the following simple table design:

Table Master (Id bigint PK, Message nvarchar(50))

Sample row in Master
101, "Foo"

Table Detail (Id bigint PK, MasterId bigint FK to Master PK, Code nvarchar(5))

Sample rows in Detail
1001, 101, "A"
1002, 101, "B"
1003, 101, "C"

Desired output from L2S query would be something like the following-

**Id, Code(s), Message**
101, "A, B, C", "Foo"

The following L2S query gives me what I want, but is there a better way to express it?

```
from m in Master
    where m.Id == 101
    select new
    {
       mi.Id,
       Codes = string.Join(",", (from c in Detail 
                                     where c.MasterId == m.Id
                                     select c.Code).ToArray()),
       mi.Message
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purrrrfect. I'd do same, except use method syntax. Seems more "natural" to me.